# How do I get the if statement to respond correctly to user input?

Tags: python-3.x

I have been tasked with writing an air traffic control application for a local airport that only has 1 runway. When the airport is busy, planes wishing to take off or land have to wait. Implement an ATCclass that uses 2 queues, one for planes waiting to take off and another for planes wishing to land. Landing planes get priority over planes wishing to take off.

My ATC class should implement the following methods: land(sign): This method takes the flight sign and adds it to the landing queue.takeoff(sign): This method takes the flight sign and adds it to the take off queue. next(): This method looks at the queues and determines if a plane can take off or land. It then removes the plane's flight sign from the appropriate queue and prints the action and call sign. For example:
`Take off AA1943` or `Land AA1243`

Now for some reason, when I enter a number greater than 5, it do not get the required "Unknown choice! Try again..." print out on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
class ATC:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__queue_landing = []
        self.__queue_takeoff = []

    def take_off(self, flight_code):
        self.__queue_takeoff.append(flight_code)

    def land(self, flight_code):
        self.__queue_landing.append(flight_code)

    def next(self):
        if len(self.__queue_landing) > 0:
            print('Land', self.__queue_landing.pop(0))
        elif len(self.__queue_takeoff) > 0:
            print('Take off', self.__queue_takeoff.pop(0))
        else:
            print('No flights to land or take off!')


def main():

    atc = ATC()
    while True:
        print('1. Take off')
        print('2. Land')
        print('3. Next')
        print('4. Quit')
        ch = int(input("Choice: "))
        if ch < 1 or ch > 5:
            print("Unknown choice! Try again...")
        elif ch == 1:
            flight = input("Please enter a flight sign: ")
            atc.take_off(flight)
        elif ch == 2:
            flight = input("Please enter a flight sign: ")
            atc.land(flight)
        elif ch == 3:
            atc.next()
        else:
            break
        print()


main()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't solved your issue specifically, but shouldn't it be "... or ch >= 5"?
5 isn't a valid choice either but the way you have it seems like it is.

Comment: Your code will show `Unknown choice! ...` for all cases apart from ch == 5. There does not seem to be an error otherwise.